Where does the "see also" come from in a tag excerpt?
How can we control what is shown in the "see also" of the mouse-over tool tip that is shown when hovering over a tag name?
An example of this is given in the second screenshot over in this blog post.

The tags which appear in the see also field are the tags which are synonyms of the actual tag.  
If you hover over your name in the top panel, you will see an expanded scorecard.  On the top of the scorecard you will see Privileges. Clicking on it will take you to the complete list of privileges with the privileges that you have on the site clearly mentioned.  
One of the privileges is the ability to Suggest Tag Synonyms.

I wonder why it's not written "also known as" instead of "see also"...
